# Sort a deque containing struct

Tags: c++, deque

I want to sort a deque according to the int g value contained in the node struct.
The structure of my program is this:

```
struct node
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int g;  
};

deque<node> open;
```

This is the sorting function I am trying but it gives garbage values. Please guide me:

```
deque<node> sort(deque<node> t)
{
    deque<node>::iterator it;
    int size= t.size();
    node te;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<size-i; j++)
        {
            if(t[j].g < t[j+1].g)
            {
                te.x = t[j].x;
                te.y = t[j].y;
                te.g = t[j].g;

                t[j].x = t[j+1].x;
                t[j].y = t[j+1].y;
                t[j].g = t[j+1].g;

                t[j+1].x = te.x;
                t[j+1].y = te.y;
                t[j+1].g = te.g;
            }
        }
    }

    for(it=t.begin();it!=t.end();it++)
    {   
        te = *it;
        cout<<te.x<<","<<te.y<<","<<te.g<<endl;
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `std::sort`?

Comment: Please guide me how to use this function in this case. I was unaware of this function.

Comment: I want to sort the deque in descending order according to g.

Comment: Assignment works for structs: `te = t[j]`. There's also `std::swap(t[j], t[j+1]);`, not to mention `std::sort` for when you don't want to re-implement one of the worst sorting algorithms in existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you go out of bounds when `j` iterates upto `size - 1`, which results in `j+1` being equal to `size` which is out of bounds.

You can use `std::sort` which is an inbuilt C++ function.

The syntax is `std::sort(t.begin(), t.end())` where `t` is the object you want to sort.

Since you are using a struct, you will have to define an ordering, i.e. how is less than and equal to calculated. You can either overload the inbuilt operators, or define a new function and pass that as a third parameter to the `sort` function.

Answer (score 10):

You are going out of bounds when `i == 0`: you iterate `j` up to `size - 1` inclusively, but then `j + 1 == size`.

Anyway, there's much simpler and faster solution - just use `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(t.begin(), t.end(), [](const node& a, const node& b) { 
    return a.g > b.g;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
struct {
    bool operator()(node a, node b)
    {   
        return a.g < b.g;
    }   
} customLess;
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), customLess);
```

I'd generally say: if you want sorted containers, you probably need to get nodes by a given `g`. Use a [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead of `std::deque`, which will allow you to map `g` values to nodes:

```
std::multimap<int, node> nodes;
```

Comment: Why do you think OP needs `multimap`? Please note `deque` is chosen, that most probably means adding/removing at the beginning/end is quite often. Sorting can be required to add/remove min/max values. While heap is more intuitive choice in this case, deque can provide some benefits (at least heap is less known container)

Comment: @AndyT: I do agree in principle, but adding to a multimap isn't necessarily expensive, it really depends on the application. However, when you need more often than you insert extract values and sort them, using a sorted container clearly gives you an advantage, because typically, the complexity of that sort is comparable to a worst-case insert.